# Milw0rm/Packetstorm News Bot

Tags: forum, bots

I am making a security forum, so I would like to know if there is some forum bot that will get the newest posts from milw0rm and packetstorm and will post them in the forum ?
One friend of mine told me that there is such thing, but after some google searches i was not able to find it. Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) on the scraping.

Answer (score 0):

If the sites you described provide some form of RSS, you could use an RSS reader that's freely available on the net to add the posts to your forum.

Comment: Excuse me, can you tell me more about using that RSS reader ?

Comment: A RSS is simply an XML file. So with an XmlReader you can create what you need.